# How can I find all non-executable files in a directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

What option should be used in `find` command in Linux for listing non executable file in directory?

Answer (score 12):

Depends on your definition of *executable*, in this context.

If you mean files that **you** (current user) are allowed to execute, then you can use something like this (finds non-executable regular files; no directories)

```
find . -type f ! -executable
```

If instead, you mean files which have the `+x` permission set (for their owner or group or everyone), then i believe you want something like this (finds regular files; no directories; which do not have `u+x`, `g+x` nor `o+x`)

```
find . -type f ! -perm /0111
```